# Does field size affect group by performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have a query where I am grouping by a column with very large fields (most have thousands of chars) and seeing a performance hit. Grouping by other smaller columns does not have a proportional affect on performance.

My intuition is that the group by is based on hashing so size doesn't matter (I can't find docs on under the hood behavior)

Could there be something else at play here or does field size somehow affect performance of the group by?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Group by may use a hash or a sort.  Of course, a huge column adds overhead either way, perhaps worse with hash (the cost of all the multiply and add goes up, while a compare can get done on the first different byte).  If there are multiple columns in the group by, putting smaller columns first may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My intuition is that the group by is based on hashing so size doesn't matter

I'm a little confused by this reaction.  Hashing requires processing the entire value of the key for two key operations:

1. Producing the hash value.
2. Checking for collisions in the hash table.

I am not intimately familiar with the Postgres implementation of hash tables, but large key values also run the risk of eating up memory -- and that is going to slow down any algorithm.

I would expect hashing to have performance proportional to the key lengths.

Comment: My intuition was wrong! I was only considering the output of the hash, while ignoring the input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a combined index on the fields that are being grouped?

Comment: One might want to avoid a hash index for huge columns!